# Disable Copy/Paste/Right Click in mvc TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a textbox which accepts numeric value.This is handled using javascript. 
I'd like to disable copy, paste and right click functionalities for the text box.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Days, new { @class = "input_box", @id = "txtDays", @onkeydown = "javascript:NumberOnly(this,event)"})
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by using `oncopy` and `onpaste` event:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Days, 
                  new { 
                        @class = "input_box", 
                        id = "txtDays",
                        oncopy="return false", 
                        onpaste="return false" 
                      }
                   )
```

You may want to visit [this article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/jquery/D9UO110612-Disable-cut,-copy-and-paste-in-textbox-using-jquery,-javascript.html) which explains couple of ways to do it.

Comment: You're missing a comma after the `oncopy` one but other than that this is perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following code might help you out.

```
$('#txtDays').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
});
```